# Two arrays into one by the number of the first one

Tags: java, arrays, list

I have two lists like this:

```
 1. [apple, orange]
 2. [cyan, magenta, yellow, black]
```

I want the algorithm to print like this:

```
 1. [apple:cyan,magenta]
 2. [orange:yellow, black]
```

What am I doing wrong?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
String file_name_Colors = "D:/colors.txt";
String file_name_Fruts = "D:/fruts.txt";
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
int number_Colors;
int number_Fruts;
number_Colors = input.nextInt();
number_Fruts = input.nextInt();
try{
ReadFileColors fileColors = new ReadFileColors(file_name_Colors, number_Colors);
ReadFileFruts fileFruts = new ReadFileFruts(file_name_Fruts, number_Fruts);
String[] aryLines = fileColors.OpenFileColors();
String[] aryLinesFruts = fileFruts.OpenFileFruts();
List<String> listColorPleaseTY = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> listFruts_Fruts = new ArrayList<>();
int numberColorPlease;
int numberFrutsPlease;
for(numberColorPlease=0; numberColorPlease<aryLines.length; numberColorPlease++){
    listColorPleaseTY.add(aryLines[numberColorPlease]);
}
for(numberFrutsPlease=0; numberFrutsPlease<aryLinesFruts.length; numberFrutsPlease++){
    listFruts_Fruts.add(aryLinesFruts[numberFrutsPlease]);
}
System.out.println(listFruts_Fruts);
System.out.println(listColorPleaseTY);

List<String> subItemslistnewone = new ArrayList<String>(listColorPleaseTY.subList(0, number_Colors));
System.out.println(subItemslistnewone);
    } catch (IOException e){ System.out.println( e.getMessage() ); }
}
```

Comment: please share the code you write so far.

Comment: color is already defined ?

Comment: Do you want to match always two colors to one given fruit? Or what criteria do you use?

Comment: numbers, i want a x amount of fruits to assign to a x amount of colors

Comment: Please define the problem you're trying to solve properly (a single example requires a lot of assumptions) and also the problem you're having with your code (we shouldn't have to run it ourselves to figure it out).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about of distribution criteria, do you need something like this?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<String> fruits = Arrays.asList("apple","orange");
    List<String> colours = Arrays.asList("cyan","magenta","yellow","black");
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<>(fruits.size());
    for (int i = 0; i < fruits.size(); i++) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(fruits.get(i));
        sb.append(":");
        int begin = (i*colours.size())/fruits.size() + 1;
        int end = ((i+1)*colours.size())/fruits.size();
        sb.append(colours.get(begin-1));
        for (int j = begin; j < end; j++) {
            sb.append(",");
            sb.append(colours.get(j));
        }
        result.add(sb.toString());
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println((i+1)+". ["+result.get(i)+"]");
    }
}
```

Comment: It works for only 2 fruits and 4 colors, i want it to work for a dinamic number of fruits and a dinamic number of colors, thank you very much, i have something at least. I want to assign a x amount of colors to a x amount of fruits. Thank you again.

Comment: lets say like this: List<String> fruits contains 1000 fruits and List<String> colours contains 5000, i want to assign each time a different number of fruits a diferent number of colors. One time i want to print 7 fruits with each fruit 2 colors, other time 50 fruits with 10 color each.

Comment: Thank you very much, i've modified it and its what i wanted. Thank you.